# Java error handling for project- Line matched except underscores: Invalid Event Code_?

Tags: java

I completed this java project for a class, but I cannot seem to fix the error I'm getting for the web software that grades it- it's called webcat. I've tried the test input the software suggests for a reference test against my solution, and my output looks exactly the same, but I still lost points for this error-

"Error in method main of class Event: Line number 2 of your output is incorrect (line numbers begin at 1). Your main method does not print the correct output when the input is "This is a short test " (input less than 26 characters) [] Line matched except underscores: Invalid Event Code_".

How can I fix this error when the expected ouput looks fine? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
   public class Event {
/**
 * accepts coded event info, prints the info back to std output, and 
   actual cost and prize number.
 *
 * @param args Command line arguments - not used.
 */  

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // variables needed 
      String shrink, event, date, time, section, row, seat; 
      double price, discount, cost; 
      int prizeNum; 
      
      // accept input 
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in); 
      
      // format the numbers 
      DecimalFormat formatNum = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00"); 
      
      // enter input and trim the space 
      System.out.print("Enter your event code: ");    
      shrink = userInput.nextLine().trim(); 
      
      if (shrink.length() < 26) { 
         System.out.println(); 
         System.out.println("Invalid Event Code");
         System.out.println("Event code must have at least 26 characters."); 
         return;   
      } 
      
      // locates spot in index of code and assigns 
      event = shrink.substring(25, shrink.length()); 
      date = shrink.substring(0, 8); 
      time = shrink.substring(8, 12); 
      section = shrink.substring(19, 21); 
      row = shrink.substring(21, 23); 
      seat = shrink.substring(23, 25); 
      
      price = Double.parseDouble(shrink.substring(12, 15) 
              + "." + shrink.substring(15, 17)); 
      discount = Double.parseDouble(shrink.substring(17, 19));
      
      // calculates final cost 
      cost = price - (price * (discount / 100)); 
      
      // random final number 
      prizeNum = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 + 1); 
      
      // prints the data to std output    
      System.out.println(); 
      System.out.print("Event: " + event + " " + " " + " "); 
      
      System.out.print("Date: " + date.substring(0, 2) + "/"  
                     + date.substring(2, 4) + "/" + date.substring(4, 8) + " " 
                     + " " + " "); 
      
      System.out.println("Time: " + time.substring(0, 2) + ":" 
                      + time.substring(2, 4) + " " + " " + " ");  
      
      System.out.print("Section: " + section + " " + " " + " "); 
      System.out.print("Row: " + row + " " + " " + " "); 
      System.out.println("Seat: " + seat); 
      
      System.out.print("Price: " + formatNum.format(price) + " " + " " + " "); 
      
      // formats discount before print
      formatNum.applyPattern("#.#'%'");
      System.out.print("Discount: " + formatNum.format(discount) + " "  
                       + " " + " "); 
      
      // formats cost before print 
      formatNum.applyPattern("$#,##0.00"); 
      System.out.println("Cost: " + formatNum.format(cost));  
      
     
      System.out.print("Prize Number: " + prizeNum);
```

Output:

```
Enter your event code: This is a short test

Invalid Event Code

Event code must have at least 26 characters.
```

[image]

Comment: You should print an underscore after "Code" in "Invalid Event Code".

Comment: There’s a fullstop/period at the end of the error message in the description.